# i18n issues - translations being swapped

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, closures, i18next

I am are trying to use nodejs/express to build several vhosts. Each vhost will have a set of localized files (translation.json). I tried to create multiple instances of i18n components, say we have the following sites

```
foo.bar.ca (canada)
foo.bar.fr (france)
foo.bar.cn (china)
```

I am trying to do something like:

```
var i18n = require('i18n'); 
    app.use(i18nOrg.initMW(app, siteObj.locale, instance(i18nOrg)));

==================================================================================
//Below is the i18nOrg = require('../i18nOrg')
// init middleware
module.exports.initMW = function(app, locale, i18nOrg) {
    return function(req, res, next) {

        i18nOrg.configure({
            updateFiles: false,
            objectNotation: true,
            directory: process.cwd() + '/app/locales/' + locale,
            prefix: 'translation',
            register: global,
            queryParameter: 'lang',
            defaultLocale: locale
        });

        app.locals.i18n = instance(i18nOrg);
        res.locals.i18n = instance(i18nOrg);

        next();
    };
};
==================================================================================
```

So now, the issue is that sometimes i see the english translation in the french site.

Anyone could help me with this?

Thanks.